# How can I get the current system date and time using a command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch, command-line

I would like to get the current system date and time using a command prompt.
How do I get the date to be in a specific format, `MM-DD-YYYY HH:MIN AM/PM`?

Answer (score 5):

Very easy to get the date and time, actually:

```
set Year=
for /f "skip=2" %%x in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime get Year^,Month^,Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Second /Format:List') do (
  if not defined Year set %%x
)
```

I'm assuming local time here. If you need UTC, adapt it accordingly.

Your format makes things more complicated. Apologies if I get something wrong here, I'm not familiar with am/pm formats.

```
if %Hour% LSS 12 (
  set ampm=AM
  if %Hour%==0 set Hour=12
) else (
  set ampm=PM
  set /a Hour-=12
)
```

We need a few leading zeroes:

```
if %Month% LSS 10 set Month=0%Month%
if %Day% LSS 10 set Day=0%Day%
if %Minute% LSS 10 set Minute=0%Minute%
if %Hour% LSS 10 set Hour=0%Hour%
```

Then it's time to assemble the parts:

```
set Timestamp=%Month%-%Day%-%Year% %Hour%:%Minute% %ampm%
```

<sub>(Just a random note: Why on earth would you want that timestamp format?)</sub>

Comment: nice solution! in some countries, "day" goes before "month" in a date string...

Comment: but your solution functions only with admin privileges...

Comment: kokbira: It works fine here as a normal user.

Comment: mmm. perhaps for Windows 7 it functions, but for Windows XP it doesn't with normal user

Answer (score 3):

Unix command line tools are often more powerful than their windows counterparts.

But even with Windows you can use some ported command line tools. For example the free UnxTools package:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/
```

Here's the download link:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/UnxUtils.zip/download
```

Just take the date.exe from the archive (it's in the subfolder usr\local\wbin) and put it in a folder you also have in your PATH environment.

Then you can call the date.exe with parameters like this:

```
date.exe +"%m-%d-%y %l:%M %p"
```

If you want to see all possible formating patterns simply call

```
date.exe --help
```

Please take care to include the ".exe" extension. If you leave it off then windows will call the internal date command.

Answer (score 3):

```
:: construct date and time strings
:: "MM-DD-YYYY HH:MIN AM/PM"
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%u in ('date /t') do set d=%%v 
for /f "tokens=1" %%u in ('time /t') do set t=%%u 
for /f "tokens=2" %%u in ('time /t') do set a=%%u
if "%t:~1,1%"==":" set t=0%t% 
set datestr=%d:~0,2%-%d:~3,2%-%d:~6,4% %t:~0,2%:%t:~3,2% %a%
```

I use variations of this block of code in nearly every .bat file I write.

Use "%datestr%" to get your date string, i.e.:

echo %datestr%

Comment: nice, but you forgot in some countries default date and time format are different (for example, in my country the default time format is 24h - without "am/pm")

Answer (score 0):

See Stack Overflow question *[How to get a UNIVERSAL Windows batch file timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747468/how-to-get-a-universal-windows-batch-file-timestamp)* for an example of how to get an date time setting that is independent of regional settings. To call the script,

```
c:\> cscript //nologo myscript.vbs
```

Use a `for` loop to capture the output if needed.

Comment: i am getting the dayof the week which is not required.

Comment: you specified `DD`. Isn't that what you want?  go to here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=01592c48-207d-4be1-8a76-1c4099d7bbb9 and download the vbscript manual. For hours and min, try Hour() , minute()

Comment: i require the DD value in numeric form . but it also displays it as thu which i need to delete .