# How can I access a more accurate time in a command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, time

I am running a batch script to retrieve information from a device. Tieing this up with a separate log file requires accuracy greater than the minute accuracy I can get using `time /t`.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/277333/how-can-i-get-the-current-system-date-and-time-using-command-prompt) has a method I wasn't aware of using `wmic`, but that only allows access to time up to 1 second accuracy (technically, you can ask for milliseconds - but the answer is always NULL).

Comment: Even though the command prompt is "aka DOS", it is *not* DOS.

Answer (score 6):

I had forgotten that the command prompt has some built in variables.

Use %TIME%

```
set dt=%DATE%-%TIME%
echo %dt%
```

gives
    26/10/2011-15:08:19.09